# How to check whether its real image or renamed it from .exe file

Tags: asp.net, validation, file-upload

I have used ASP.Net File upload control after user select file i have check file type really image file or renamed it from .exe file.

I used below code

```
 If FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType <> "image/jpeg" Then
                Label1.Text = "Not real Image"
End If
```

Its work well in IE browser but not work in Firefox and Google chrome any solution is there?

Answer (score 1):

You can check the first few bytes of the file, for the JPEG magic bytes (`ff d8`). If the file doesn't start with those, it's not a JPEG file.

Comment: It's in my answer; `ff d8` are the first two bytes of a JPEG image.